# Definite Integral: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d \theta }{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\cos( \theta )}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

> I need integral result for following integral:
>   $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d \theta }{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\cos( \theta )}}$$

It will be useful in an electromagnetic simulator. It is obtained as the medium 1/distance from one ring to a point that is separated to the axis.
Actually due the objects where split in a 3-d mesh of 24k pieces so to solve the problem its takes 3 hours due inverse of 24k x 24k arrays (that reach the 16GB limit of RAM).

I have look for at definite integral tables but was not found
It would help an APPROXIMATE solution that reduces the 3-D problem to 2D.
It is said it is a first kind elliptic integral, but I do not know how to place in an elliptic expression and what lib can be used with C++. Boost is included in actual C++11 but I do not know if the elliptic integral lib is included in it

Comment: This is indeed a complete elliptic integral of the first kind. Ask WA the correct parameterization.

Comment: it is not squared sine but single cosine

Comment: You very easily turn it to the canonical form. Some effort on your side might help.

Comment: I am sorry,  my effors where made to obtain the integral from electromagnetics formulas

Comment: Hint: Half-angle formula.

Comment: Unless otherwise mentioned, on MSE normally integral question asks for closed form expressions (or if the exist). If you need an approximation you should mention this.

Comment: I will try, thank you, but I do not understand why is better to use elliptic integral than making a direct c++ integral by a long sum

Comment: Elliptic integrals are in standard libraries and are normally implemented much more efficient and accurate than using a custom sum.

Comment: What library do you recommend me in c++ that uses multithreads?

Comment: I am not using C++, so no recommendation. I IMO Boost is well-resprected, 
see e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/ellint/ellint_1.html

Comment: Thank you for your useful response, boost can be included in a C++ project.

Answer (score 0):

The response is:
$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d \theta }{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\cos( \theta )}}=2\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d \theta }{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\cos( \theta )}}$$

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt }{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\cos(2t)}}=4\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt }{\sqrt{1-k^{2}(1-2sin^2(t))}}=4\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt }{\sqrt{(1-k^{2})+2k^2sin^2(t)}}$$
That is an elliptic integral of the first order.

Result can be found here:
[Forum math](http://rinconmatematico.com/foros/index.php?topic=105198.0)

Where
$$\theta=2t$$

I used boost and worked. Elliptic integrals are included in  in C++17, so it is not needed install boost:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>


const double PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
const double PI2 = 2.0 * PI;

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double flimit = PI, k = 0.25, f;
    f = ellint_1(k, flimit);
    double expected = 1.596242222131783510149;
    cout << "Ellint error for k,F=" << k << " & " << flimit << " = " << fabs(f - expected) << endl;

    cout << endl << "=== END ===" << endl; getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind), we get a complete elliptic integral of the first kind viz. $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\cos\theta}}=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\cos\theta}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2k^{2}}{k^{2}-1}\sin^{2}\phi}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}}}K\left(\sqrt{\frac{2k^{2}}{k^{2}-1}}\right).$$As discussed therein, the easiest fast accurate calculation for a given $k$ uses the aithmetic-geometric mean.